# Cannot display the AutoCompleteBox in Blend

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I have a problem with the Autocompletebox control which doesn't work in Blend which complains that the TypeConverter for the InputScope property cannot convert from a string. The control works fine at run time and displays fine in the VS2010 designer.

Is there an easy way can either just disable the control entirely or swap it out for a simple textblock at design time only?

Better still does anyone know how I could just make the AutoCompleteBox work in blend as is?

Edit:
I've found that if I just remove the setting of the InputScope property then the AutoCompleteBox displayes fine. So how can I programaticly remove just that portion of the XAML (InputScope="Search") when in design mode?

Comment: where is this converter defined?

Comment: The control itself is part of the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.
The InputScopeConverter is defined in System.Windows.Input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, after I created a default style for this control, it doesn't throw me any error anymore... And I have no idea why... I think it is a bug. :)

```
    <Style TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Margin="8,7"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0,6,4"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox x:Name="Text" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" InputScope="{TemplateBinding InputScope}" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <ListBox x:Name="Selector" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="White" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" IsTabStop="False" ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}" Opacity="{TemplateBinding Opacity}" Padding="0,8"/>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I was after. I just wanted a simple way to ignore the InputScope property so the control could be displayed in Blend.

Comment: Correction: Seems this is in fact the only workaround as my solution affects the app at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is incredibly easy.

Just add the mc:Ignorable prefix to the attribute to be ignored. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024.aspx

In other words just prefix the InputScope attribute with d:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox d:InputScope="Search"/>
```

Comment: well, i assume you still want the InputScope set to "Search" at run time right? if so this won't work, d: means it is only for blend's design time

Comment: Ah, OK. Must admit I didn't check it stilled worked at runtime! School boy error.

Comment: Is there not a version of flag that only works at design time?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of... You can just put the default style in you app.xaml, it's a quick workaround for now